# Check if android OCR is downloaded or not

Tags: android, android-vision

I have used OCR, from google vision api, where I used the app to detect text from screen using text recognizer API. But, as the document says, it needs to download the necessary files from the internet and it says that it downloads when the app is downloaded from play store

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr" />
```

Is there any way how I can check if the necessary files are downloaded or not? If not, I want to start the download, once the user gets connected to wifi.

Comment: only gradle dependency is required and nothing else.

Comment: does it download automatically if I put in play store?

Comment: when you add gradle dependecy in gradle file it auto download required file. and when you make apk then all the required file are bundled automatically. you don't need to take tension. after making signed apk you just need to upload over play store.

Comment: But, when I tried in other devices, it goes to textRecognizationApi is not operational.